# How to use regular snapshots of audio in animation with AudioKit in Swift?

Tags: swift, audiokit

I have an LFO (phasor) and I want to animate it.

For example, a rectangle should change its offset based on the current signal value of the LFO.

How do I get a momentary value from an Audio Node to use it as a regular variable to drive the animation?